# eBay Marketplace account deletion endpoint validation failed

Tags: c#, .net, ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

Marketplace account deletion endpoint validation failed. Click here to learn more about setting up an endpoint.

I have created an API method to respond challenge response to eBay. But validation is failing I am not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Below is the code logic I added.

```
 public ActionResult<string> ChallengeResponse([FromQuery] string challenge_code)
    {
        try
        {
            string verificationToken = _configuration["eBayVerificationToken"];
            string endpoint = _configuration["eBayNotificationEndPoint"];
            string challengeResponse = string.Empty;
            IncrementalHash sha256 = IncrementalHash.CreateHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            sha256.AppendData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(challenge_code));
            sha256.AppendData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(verificationToken));
            sha256.AppendData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(endpoint));
            byte[] bytes = sha256.GetHashAndReset();
            challengeResponse = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
            JObject json = JObject.Parse("{\"challengeResponse\":\"" + challengeResponse + "\"}");
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add more in what is the error you are receiving

Comment: Title is the error

Comment: Marketplace account deletion endpoint validation failed. Click here to learn more about setting up an endpoint.

Comment: is there a exception?

Comment: No, ebay validation failed error

Answer (score 0):

I used a object with challenge response to the one member:

```
class challengeResponseObj
{
    public string challengeResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Then I just assign the value of the response and return the object as a JSON result:

```
challengeResponseObj resObj = new challengeResponseObj()
{
    challengeResponse = resMessage
};
return new JsonResult(resObj);
```